# If querying a not-existed time series (because name has changed), what will Apache IoTDB respond?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

My case requires data to be stored in multiple different time series with continually changing serial number set in the name of time series of Apache IoTDB. Since the name of time series may be changing, I may encounter querying using the old name of time series, so this time series should not be existed in the new system. I want to know how will Apache IoTDB respond to non-existent time series? What message will the system mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache IoTDB will not report any error for non-existent time series. For example if you get the name of time series wrong in the query statement, IoTDB will only not display this wrongly named time series by default, so if you check any time series that did not display in the result, you can check if you name it right.